# Array to json and row to json in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016

```
[{"User":[{"UserName":"abc","EmailId":"abc@gmail.com","UserId":1,"UserType":"0","User_Level":0},{"UserName":"jack","EmailId":"jack@gmail.com","UserId":1618,"UserType":"1","User_Level":0}]}]
```

How can I use this json in a `select` statement of SQL Server 2016?

I want a select statement which returns output like above json

Comment: Could you provide your sample data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to use `FOR JSON AUTO` with `ROOT`

```
SELECT UserName,EmailId,UserId,UserType,User_Level
FROM T
FOR JSON AUTO,ROOT('USER')
```